# Trying to protect route by using admin guard and calling and api inside it to verify the data

Tags: angular

I have made an admin guard. I am calling an api and extracting the id.

I have to return true or false accordingly. I cannot put return inside the callback. If i do then I get an error "function must return a value". It doesn't pick up return statement inside the callback.

Now this code doesnt work because the if statement out side the callback is executed before the call back finishes and before the correct data is fetched.
What should I do ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
userDetail: any;
isAdmin = false;
  constructor( 
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  canActivate(

    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe((res: any)=>{
        this.userDetail = res.data;
        if(this.userDetail.id == 2) {
          this.isAdmin = true;
        }
      });
      if(this.isAdmin) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not subscribe. Angular will handle the subscription for you:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authService.getUserProfile().pipe(
    take(1), // add this if your authService doesn't complete after getting profile
    map((res) => res.data.id == 2)
  );
}
```

Comment: Man, I never thought about doing it in this way. Pretty cool!

Comment: @DanielPiñeiro rxjs is the best thing since sliced bread :D but it takes a while to get used to

Answer (score 0):

`CanActivate` can be a `Observable<boolean>` or  `Promise<boolean>` or `Boolean`. With this on mind you can return a promise or an observable`.

I would use a `promise` like this:

```
   canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
       return new Promise((resolve) => 
          this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe((res: any)=>{
            resolve(res.data.id == 2);
        });
  }
```